# SSIS copy files task

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a list of file paths in a table. I need to read these file paths copy these files to a drive which is on present on another server without changing the directory structure. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this in SSIS in the following way:

1. Create a Data Flow Task. In the Data Flow Task, add a Data source component to fetch the filenames from the table. Add a Recordset Destination component and connect the two
2. Create a For Each container. Connect to the Data Flow Task created in step 1. Change the enumerator type to ADO enumerator
3. In the For Each task, add a Script Task that takes the file name and uses [System.IO.File::Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee432134.aspx) method to copy the file to its destination.

Comment: I have a file \\server 1\docs$\12-16-2008\GREENCLEMENT93651.jpg
I need to copy it to 
 \\server 2\docs$\12-16-2008\GREENCLEMENT93651.jpg
How can i keep the directory structure ?

Comment: The [System.IO.Directory::CreateDirectory][1] method will create a directory path for you. You would call this function in the Script Task

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee432161.aspx